# php soap-server - complex type from client to server

Tags: php, web-services, soap, parameters

I want to send a list of article-no to my server an get a response list back.

So I wrote a server to catch the request.

my server is very simple at the moment because I'm stuck on the params:

```
$SOAPServer = new SoapServer("testws.wsdl");
$SOAPServer->addFunction('getArticleInfoList');
$SOAPServer->handle();

function getArticleInfoList($parameters)
{
  $fd = fopen("./___log.dat", "w+");
  fwrite($fd, print_r($parameters,1)."\n");
  fclose($fd);
  // ...
  return $returnval;
}
```

In my client I call the function:

```
// client-connection is ok !
$arts[] = array('articleid'=>'4711');
$arts[] = array('articleid'=>'0815');
$params = array(
  'parameters' => array('userid'=>$userid,'articlelist'=>$arts)
);
$params = array('userid'=>$userid,'articlelist'=>$arts);

$result = $client3->__soapCall("getArticleInfoList",array("parameters" =>$params)  );
echo $client3->__getLastRequest();
echo $client3->__getLastResponse();
```

The wsdl-file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://server.de/ws/testws"  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="testws" targetNamespace="http://server.de/ws/testws">
  <wsdl:types> 
  <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://server.de/ws/testws/" elementFormDefault="qualified">
      <xsd:complexType name="Article">
        <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="articleid" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="getArticleInfoListInput">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="userid" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="articlelist" type="tns:Article[]" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:complexType name="getArticleInfoListOutput">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="articleid" type="xsd:string"></xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="price" type="xsd:decimal"></xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types> 
  <wsdl:message name="getArticleInfoListSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getArticleInfoListInput" name="parameters" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="getArticleInfoListSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:getArticleInfoListOutput" name="parameters"/>
  </wsdl:message>  
  <wsdl:portType name="testwsSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="getArticleInfoList">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:getArticleInfoListSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:getArticleInfoListSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>   
  </wsdl:portType>   
  <wsdl:binding name="testwsSoapHttpBinding" type="tns:testwsSoap">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="getArticleInfoList">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://server.de/ws/testws/"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="ShopService">
    <wsdl:documentation>TEST</wsdl:documentation>
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:testwsSoapHttpBinding" name="ShopServiceSOAP11prt_HTTP">
      <soap:address location="http://server.de/ws/testws/testws.php5"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

If I check the params in the

```
stdClass Object
(
    [item] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [key] => userid
                    [value] => F37BF361-7873-7741-2545-532F22D30781
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [key] => articlelist
                    [value] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Map] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [item] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [key] => articleid
                                                    [value] => 4711
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [item] => stdClass Object
                                                (
                                                    [key] => articleid
                                                    [value] => 0815
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

why is this such a construct ??

I just want to have the userid an the list of article id's ??

I hope somebody can help me with this.

Comment: having the same issue. any solution so far?